# Styling link: Which state for a link that is being visited?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

For a project, I need to create a small navigation menu. This menu only has two links `Accommodations` and `Activities`. And I want to add some styling to these links, more precisely when I'm on the page of the link or I hover on the link, I want the corresponding link to change color and have a blue overline
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s3WK.png).

To do that I tried to search the corresponding state, but I couldn't find it, neither `:active` or `:visited` could do what I wished for.

Here is my code:

```css
header{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 32px;
}

.nav-button{
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 16px;
}

.nav-button:hover{
    color: #0065FC;
    border-top: 2px solid #0065FC;
    padding-top: 38px;
}
```

```html
        <header>
   <nav>
     <a class="nav-button" href="#accommodations">Accommodations</a>
     <a class="nav-button" href="#activities">Activities</a>
   </nav>
</header>
```

**P.S: By the way, for this project I can only use HTML and CSS, so no JS.**

Comment: :target is pseudo class you look for here

Comment: @G-Cyrillus — No, it isn't. `:target` means "The `id` of this element matches the fragment identifier portion of the URL in the address bar" and **not** "The `href` of this link matches the URL in the address bar". The question is about styling the link, not what has been linked to.

Comment: @Quentin why? , it links to anchor in the document istself ..

Comment: @G-Cyrillus `:target` applies to the element that _gets_ targeted, not the link that contained the anchor referring to it.

Comment: @CBroe , oki, but if it is a challenge , you can still do it https://jsfiddle.net/w1qc5m6x/ with :target (flex or grid to use order is the work around for the use of :target)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS has no pseudo-class meaning "The href attribute of this link matches the URL currently shown in the address bar".

The usual way get that effect you would need to use a programming language (either server-side or client-side) to add a class to the link, and then use a regular class selector.

Comment: I see, so it's impossible to do what I want to do with only CSS. It looks like there must be a mistake on my project brief --'. Anyway, thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: @Heraxia is your project a challenge ? if so , here is a possible work around with :target. https://jsfiddle.net/w1qc5m6x/ If it is about a serious /pro page, forget it